# CoreLocation Framework: Does locationManager send a message with filled in parameters everytime it logs a new location?

Tags: objective-c, core-location

In the process of learning iOS development and I am currently being taught how to use the core location framework.

I'm told that we need to create an instance of `CLLocationManager`, and then set a delegate, then implement this method:

```
-(void) locationManager: (CLLocationManager*)manager
    didUpdateToLocation: (CLLocation*)newLocation
           fromLocation: (CLLocation*)oldLocation
```

The book doesn't thoroughly explain how the location is actually received. From what I'm understanding, whenever locationManager logs a new location, it then sends a message (to the delegate?) with the selector being the above method, filling the parameters with the location data? Then we must implement this method and choose what to do with these parameters.

Is this correct? and if not, could someone explain to me exactly what is going on?

Thanks in advance, this is confusing me a ton.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right, although the message you should implement starting in iOS 6 is `-locationManager:didUpdateLocations:`. After setting up the delegate, call `-startUpdatingLocation` and the Location Manager will start sending `-locationManager:didUpdateLocations:` (or the other method) whenever the location changes until you tell it to stop. Your implementation of that method an do whatever you like -- update a position on a map, log the location to a file, look up the nearest gas stations... There's some reason that you're asking for location updates, and whatever that reason is, this lets you do it.

Comment: Thank you! Could you tell me where all this action is taking place? What is it exactly that is sending this message?

Comment: It's the CLLocationManager object that you created.